# How to know if Linux overwrote windows boot loader

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, multi-boot

Currently my computer boots directly into Windows, but I can boot into BIOS to choose Linux's GRUB, so I'd like to know if I could safely delete Linux's partitions and allocate them back into windows 10 or if I'd brick my computer in the process

Answer (score 1):

**If it boots Windows directly the system is UEFI, not BIOS.**

And yes, you can safely delete the Ubuntu partitions. Now, what you will probably do after that - expanding one or more partitions - is generally safe but any partition operation has intrinsic risks.

Always have a current backup before doing such drastic changes.